# Independence and Fubini's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, independence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I just want to make sure I understand a detail in the proof of the following result in my book:

**Proposition.** Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent real random variables. Then

$$E\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i\Big)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i)$$

if all $X_i$ are non-negative or if each is integrable. In the second case the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is also integrable.

**Proof.** Let $Q:=\bigotimes_{i=1}^n P_{X_i}$ denote the joint distribution of $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Then by the change-of-variable formula and Tonelli's theorem

$$E\Big(\Big\lvert \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i \Big\rvert\Big)=\int | x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n| Q(dx)
=\int\dots\int |x_1|\cdot ...\cdot|x_n| P_{X_1}(dx_1)...P_{X_n}(dx_n)$$

$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\int |x_i|P_{X_i}(dx_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}E(|X_i|)$$
Hence the assertion in the case that all $X_i\geq 0$, as well as the integrability of $\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ in the case that each $X_i$ is integrable. In the latter case by Fubini's theorem the computations above remain valid if we remove all the absolute value signs.

**Question:**

Usually when applying Fubini's theorem the iterated integrals are only defined a.e. with respect to the product measure of the coordinates in which integration has not yet occured, which could invalidate the third equality above when absolute values are removed. However I think in this case this does not happen because each $X_i$ is assumed to be integrable, and hence the iterated integrals are can be defined  on the whole product space of the coordinates in which integration has not yet occured, and measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra of that space.

For example, on the first iteration Fubini's theorem tells us that $$\int x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n dP_{X_1}= x_2\cdot ...\cdot x_n \int x_1 dP_{X_1}$$ is defined $\otimes_{i=2}^n \mu_i$ a.e. and also $\otimes_{i=2}^n \mu_i$ integrable when extending it (on a null set) to a measurable function on $\times_{i=2}^n \Omega_i$. Hence we are free to define $$\int x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n dP_{X_1}dx_1:= x_2\cdot ...\cdot x_n \int x_1 dP_{X_1}$$ on such a null set to integrate. Repeated application of this reasoning with respect to each coordinate then gives us the product of integrals.

Is this right way to think about this? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, in this case each of the integrands are fully defined rather than only a.e..

Comment: @TeresaLisbon And if the iterated integrals where only defined a.e. we could not obtain the third equality right?

Comment: I am not sure about this question, I actually still think things could work if the integrand was a.e. defined.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon I think you are right, since the way we define the integral on a set of measure zero does not change the result of the next integration. For example, the first iteration tells us that $\int x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n dP_{X_1}= x_2\cdot ...\cdot x_n \int x_1 P_{X_1}$ is defined $\otimes_{i=2}^n \mu_i$ a.e. and $\otimes_{i=2}^n \mu_i$ integrable. But we are free to define  $\int x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n P_{X_1}dx_1:= x_2\cdot ...\cdot x_n \int x_1 P_{X_1}$ on this null set without changing the integral. We just need to make sure this extension is measurable, this is the case here right?

Comment: The extension will be measurable : any extension to a set of measure zero is measurable (as long as the measure space is complete, which it is here, so nothing to worry). So yes it is the case here, and with your extension, we are done! (+1 for question and resulting discussion)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon How do you know that the probability space is complete? I didn't make this assumption. I believe measurability comes directly from the fact that the function is jointly $\otimes_{i=1}^n \mu_i$ measurable.

Comment: Oh, I forgot this was not the Lebesgue measure! But then, the sets of "non-definition" is of measure zero in the individual measures (since the integrands must be measurable, hence defined on measurable subsets of the space), hence we should be able to extend these to anything on that measure zero part. I think that should do it.